# #pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wmissing-attributes" does not work

Tags: linux, gcc, pragma

I'm trying to compile Elfutils, but I get a error:

```
elfutils-0.166/libelf/libelfP.h:53:30: error: ‘__elf64_msize’ specifies less restrictive attribute than its target ‘elf64_fsize’: ‘const’ [-Werror=missing-attributes]
```

i try to solve this error by following patch

```
diff -Naur elfutils-0.166_orig/libelf/libelfP.h elfutils-0.166/libelf/libelfP.h
--- elfutils-0.166_orig/libelf/libelfP.h    2016-01-12 15:49:19.000000000 +0300
+++ elfutils-0.166/libelf/libelfP.h 2021-08-30 19:38:44.866175082 +0300
@@ -48,6 +48,8 @@
 
 
 /* Helper Macros to write 32 bit and 64 bit functions.  */
+#pragma GCC diagnostic push
+#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wmissing-attributes"
 #define __elfw2_(Bits, Name) __elf##Bits##_##Name
 #define elfw2_(Bits, Name) elf##Bits##_##Name
 #define ElfW2_(Bits, Name) Elf##Bits##_##Name
@@ -632,4 +634,5 @@
 #define INVALID_NDX(ndx, type, data) \
   unlikely ((data)->d_size / sizeof (type) <= (unsigned int) (ndx))
 
+#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
 #endif  /* libelfP.h */
```

but error appears again, i try to configure with --disable-werror option, but configure shows `configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --disable-werror` please tell me, how to solve this error?

Comment: The old elfutils-0.166  https://sourceware.org/elfutils/ftp/  can be built with gcc-6.3 (my tests : not 5.3 not 7.3) . ...... Patch `elfutils-0.166-elfcmp-comp-gcc6.patch` https://drive.google.com/file/d/1k_UrQEpL34WCIRhZR1c9mwfT5IufqTRW/view?usp=sharing ......... Any questions: Add OS name, version to your question.

Comment: thank you, i resolve this problem with command ```sed -i 's/-Werror//g' $(find . -type f -exec egrep -l _no_Werror {} \;)```